# installer like Wubi for windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-installer, wubi

I want to install windows 8 on my windows 7 machine but the problem is I can't make a new partition because there is a limit of 4 partitions at the most which I can't cross. To install windows 8 I would have to remove a partition but I want to know if there is any program like Wubi which help me installing windows 8 inside windows 7, as ubuntu is installed inside a windows computer by Wubi.

PS:I know about virtual machine and softwares like that but the problem is if I run windows 8 in virtual machine, I won't be able to allocate full system resources to windows in virtual machine. However that isnot the case if I install windows 8 like we install ubuntu with Wubi, because it would be listed in boot list.

I will be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is called [booting from a VHD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHD_%28file_format%29#Native_VHD_Boot) (Virtual Hard Disk). Assuming you have Windows 8 Pro, you can install it in a VHD file on your hard disk and boot from it as if it were installed on its own partition.

See [this article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GuideToInstallingAndBootingWindows8DeveloperPreviewOffAVHDVirtualHardDisk.aspx) for instructions (they're for the Developer Preview, but should apply to the RTM version as well).

If you have regular (non-Pro) Windows 8, you can try a program called [VBoot](http://www.vmlite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=51&Itemid=148), which should support any edition of Windows. They don't explicitly list Windows 8 support, though.

Answer (score 2):

You could always set up a virtual machine using a program like VirtualBox, and then install Windows 8 on that.

Comment: well I don't want to install using a virtual machine. I won't be able to allocate full system resources to windows 8 in virtual machine

Comment: I think Indrek's answer is more your speed then.